# Using React setState to handle error validation & handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, setstate

validation on components is currently being handled in a "base component", which wraps children in "error state" and passes `inError` props to them.

Currently the check for `showErrors` is done like so:

```
let showErrors = (component.hasServerErrors()) && (!hasFocus || component.type === "radio");
```

This basically means that when a page is submitted, the `hasServerErrors()` method is run which checks for errors on the server (not handled by UI).

This works fine for the first time a page is validated (user doesn't select a radio) - error messaging appears fine, but because `hasServerErrors()` only runs on submission of the page, the error state persists after a value is changed.

I made the following update to improve this behaviour:

```
const [resolvedErrors, setResolvedErrors] = useState(false);

let showErrors = (!resolvedErrors ? component.hasServerErrors() : false) && (!hasFocus || component.type === "radio");

  const handleChange = (e: SyntheticEvent<FormInputElements>) => {
    handleEvent(onChange, e.currentTarget.value);

    if (hasFocus && showErrors) {
      setResolvedErrors(true);
    }
  };
```

This solved my issue of "resolving" the error state meaning that when an element was inError, and they selected a valid option, the error state would disappear. However, it's not a robust solution as if a user selects a valid option, then de-selects it, this is not picked up and means the user is no longer aware what element is in error.

Can anyone suggest a way I could combine `showErrors` and `resolvedErrors` into one concise state, so that error handling could be properly managed?